# how to use a project from github in my eclipse web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, github

I'd like to use this 
https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker

I have imported from github
I now have a Project in eclipse called jquery-timepicker

But I cant add it to my server, it's not a Web Project. 
What do I do now ?, do I need to make a package of some kind so it can be included in my Web Appication project ?

Comment: You don't need to clone the source to use it; download a zip of the source, place the references to the js/css in the head of your document, and use as described.

Comment: that's an answer surely. so I cant vote you and we're not allowed to show common decency ;)

Comment: Six hours ago I was about to leave, so I didn't have time to write a full answer.

Comment: Did my answer not answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to clone an entire repository just to use the scripts contained within; for github, there is a button in the lower right-hand corner, 'Download ZIP'; this will get you the current files contained within the repository.

From there, one simply adds the files to their project directory, and into whatever sub-folder organization is used(root/js/etc).

Lastly, reference the files in your project's document head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="relative/or/absolute/path/to/file_name.js"></script>
```

It should be noted that [source-based javascript inclusions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) cannot evaluate the contents in-between the tags themselves.. or in other words..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some/file.js">
    //any script in here is ignored
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //any script here is evaluated
</script>
```

If the script modifies the DOM(document object model)(and this script does), then it is suggested to either wait for the DOM to finish loading, or to put the script after the html.  This can be done by supplying a callback for the [onload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload), or even using jQuery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.  The other method simply involves putting the script tag at the bottom of your document, just above the closing body tag.